# Software RAID creation

Tags: raid

There were 4 drives in a raid array md2, md1, m0. 2 drives of 6TB size and 2 drives of 1TB size. I removed both the drives of 1TB size from /dev/md2. Now there are 2 drives of 6TB size each. But when df -h is done, /dev/md2 which is mounted at root(/) shows as 875GB(~=1TB) instead of 6TB. How do i make /dev/md2 to show the correct size.

Follwoing steps I performed to remove the drives from raid.

```
mdadm /dev/md2 -r /dev/sda3

mdadm /dev/md2 --fail /dev/sdc3
mdadm /dev/md2 -r /dev/sdc3

mdadm --grow /dev/md2 --raid-devices=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your raid devices consist of logical partitions, not full disks. Verify the partition sizes with the `fdisk -l` or `parted -l` commands.

### Update

Seems like you've cloned the partition table from small disk.
So you should:

- remove one of the new partitons from the raid
- change the partition size
- add the partition back into the raid
- sync the data
- do the same with other partition
- change the raid size with `mdadm --grow /dev/md2 --size=max` command.
- change the filesystem size (for EXT fs use `resize2fs` command, for example)

Readings:

- [The linux raid wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing)

Comment: fdisk -l shows Disk /dev/md2: 889.6 GiB. But cat /proc/mdstat shows that /dev/md2 uses drive sdb and sdd which is of size 6TB each. But df -h shows /dev/md2 as 875Gb instead of 6TB

Comment: Check the disks, not the raid devices. `fdisk -l /dev/sda`, `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and so on. What are sizes of the partitions?

Comment: t shows the correct size. /dev/sda is set as  894.3 GiB, /dev/sdb to 5.5 TiB, dev/sdc to 894.3 GiB and /dev/sdd to 5.5 TiB

Comment: Paste the full outputs of `mdadm --detail /dev/md2` and `fdisk -l` into the question.

Comment: I have uplaoded the output to github.                                                                       https://github.com/shettypriy/raid/blob/master/fdisk%20-l                                         https://github.com/shettypriy/raid/blob/master/output

Comment: Please review the answer. If it helps, accept it. Otherwise update the question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I am still unable to do what you suggested. I also re-added the drives that I had removed. Could you please help me on how do i go forward. I wnat 2 drives on the raid array and one TB drive should be added as /dev/md3 raid which will be mounted on the folder /mnt

Comment: Check the link in the answer - you'll find the detailed steps description there.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?